# 1922 Cartography Lettering

Tags: typefaces, lettering, cartography

I know that is was hand lettered, but I have seen this same style on other maps. It looks similar to copperplate, but I don't think that's it. Can anyone identify the source for these lettering styles?[image]

Comment: The serif or sans serif font?

Answer (score 2):

The serif could be replaced by [Copper Bowles](https://creativemarket.com/RyanBowlesDesign/749701-Copper-Bowles-Rough-Serif-Font), [Copperplate hand](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/wiescher-design/copperplate-gothic-hand-31ab) or A[dorn Copperplate](https://creativemarket.com/L_Worthington/39303-Adorn-Copperplate)

The sans is trickier, but something like [Revelstoke](https://creativemarket.com/helloimgreg/1162240-Revelstoke-5-Font-Family), [Prequel](https://creativemarket.com/phitradesign/1374989-Prequel-Family) or [Davish](https://creativemarket.com/Arterfak/2895269-Davish-Font-Family)

Answer (score 1):

The larger, serifed hand is definitely someone's hand-lettered version of a Copperplate (and very nicely rendered at that) and the sans serif looks like an italic variation of one of the bauhaus style hands - I've two near matches but neither is quite perfect.

https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/borutta/vitali

https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/kostic-type-foundry/lapidary-capitals

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think Lapidary is too far off.